# Formatting Text on Summary Post BlogSpot

Tags: blogger, blogspot

[image: formatting text]

How to use formatting text on summary post Blogger/BlogSpot? i try use Bold, italic and strikethrought but still not working.

Comment: Could you share the URL of the blog where you are experiencing this issue? This is likely happening because the Auto Read More script used by your theme for summarizing posts is stripping away HTML tags from the post content (only on the home/paginated page)

Comment: https://landing-page-box.blogspot.co.id/search/label/News

Comment: and i'm using this script to display automatic summary post http://xomisse.com/blog/show-post-excerpts-with-thumbnail-on-blogger/

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding it works well but sometime it may happens because of technical glitches, you could try to write in HTML.
You can use following codes:
For bold you can write as

`<b> Your Text </b>`

and for italic you can write as

`<i> Your text </i>`

for strikethrough you can write as

`<strike> Your Text </strike>` or `<s> your text </s>`

It will work fine, However if it doesn't work to you then go to Blogger Template and check How Bold, italic and Strikethrough represents there.

Answer (score 0):

change you body style with below CSS code and try again.

```css
body {
    font: 16px Roboto, Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
    background: #fbfbfb none repeat scroll top left;
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```